# Linker is looking for the static libraries that was linked to my own static library

Tags: c++, boost, static

I have a static library that links to a statically built Boost library.
However, when my executable is linking to my own static library, it will fail with a message saying that it cannot find the Boost library.

I thought when my static library is statically linked to the Boost library, any further upstream dependency of the Boost library should be gone.  Isn't this correct?

MyLib.lib -> linked to static Boost library
MyApp.exe -> links to MyLib.lib statically, Failed!, cannot find Boost library

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _"a static library that links to a statically built Boost library"_ Static libraries aren't _linked_. You need to add the boost library, when you link your executable. Show at least your linker command line.

Answer (score 0):

Static libraries are really nothing more than a collection of object files. If you want to use a static library that depends on other libraries, you need to link withe other libraries as well.